# How can I make api keys even more secure

Tags: git, github

Currently I use `.gitignores` to secure them but if someone were to clone the repo, the keys may get exposed. Most Importantly, is there a way I can make it even more secure and accessible only in dev environment. plus, when I push the code each time into github, I accidentally don't want to reveal it either.

Comment: Can you add a bit more information? A relevant snippet of the .gitignore would add a lot more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` doesn't prevent a file to be tracked.

`.gitignore` just prevents it to be added by mistake (you have to use `git add -f`) or to see it in the untracked file list in git status (or other commands).

If the file is already tracked, it will be used and cloned.

**Do not ever commit your api keys.** If you already push them at a time, **kill your git repository with fire** or use git filter-branch. Anyone cloning your repository clones the full history with it, so removing the file won't do it.

You may want to try cloning your repository at another place to see what's inside.